# Showing statistics of popular JavaScript frameworks from GitHub API

Tags: javascript, beginner, json, ecmascript-6, promise

I am currently working on a simple app to check the stats of popular javascript frameworks. For this I am using the Github API to get certain data sets and have come close to finishing my project.

```
const frameworks = [
  {
    name: "angular",
    logo: "img/angular.png",
    url: "https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular.js"
  }
  /* 
  {
    name: "ember",
    logo: "img/ember.png",
    url: "https://api.github.com/repos/emberjs/ember.js"
  },
  {
    name: "react",
    logo: "img/react.png",
    url: "https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react"
  },
  {
    name: "vue",
    logo: "img/vue.png",
    url: "https://api.github.com/repos/vuejs/vue"
  }
  */
];

const frameworkData = url => {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(resp => {
      return resp.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      return {
        data: {
          name: data.name,
          forks: data.forks_count,
          stars: data.stargazers_count,
          issues: data.open_issues_count
        }
      };
    });
};

const setup = () => {
  let now = new Date();
  const row = document.getElementById("row");

  frameworks.forEach(framework => {
    const promises = [];
    promises.push(frameworkData(framework.url));

    Promise.all(promises).then(data => {
      const obj = data[0].data;
      console.log(obj);
      const card = `
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="${
            framework.logo
          }" alt="Card image cap" height="180" width="200">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">${framework.name}</h5>
          </div>
          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item">Watchers: ${obj.forks}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Stars: ${obj.stars}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Commits: ${obj.issues}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>`;
      row.innerHTML += card;
    });
  });
};

setup();
```

Being this is one of my first javascript 'apps' I feel it was done to the best of my ability. However, I feel there is a code smell in here that I have been trying to figure out how to fix but have not.

As you may be able to see in the frameworks for each loop, I am settings this variable `const obj = data[0].data;`. To me this is strange and I could not seem to find away around it. This is done because the single object for that API call is being returned in an array and I was not sure how to get that data other than calling the first index on the array since it will always be 0. Is there a better way to do this? How was my first javascript app?

Answer (score 1):

### Your questions

> How was my first javascript app?

Overall the code seems somewhat fine for a first attempt (barring the flaw mentioned in the first section below). It isn't difficult to read though it does have a few extra levels of nesting which could be cleaned up with abstraction code functions out to named functions.

> Is there a better way to do this?

As was suggested by others, there isn't really a point to returning the data nested under a key `"data"`. Refer also to the other suggestions below for simplifying the code.

## Other Feedback/Suggestions

### Likely implementation flaw

> ```
> frameworks.forEach(framework => {
>   const promises = [];
>   promises.push(frameworkData(framework.url));
>   Promise.all(promises)
> ```

This code will call `Promises.all()` passing an array with a single promise, which seems pointless. While there is no rule that says there has to be two or more promises it basically defeats the purpose.

Presumably you meant to push the promises into an array and pass the array with all promises to the call to `Promise.all()`.

#### Creating array of promises

One could use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to construct the array.

```
const promises = frameworks.map(framework => frameworkData(framework.url));
```

#### utilizing data

If you take the advice above, the first argument in a callback to `.then()` chained to `Promise.all()` should be an array of the data objects returned by the last promise callback within each call to `frameworkData()`, and there won’t be any reference to ‘framework`so you might either need to pass that object along through the call to`frameworkData` or look it up by index.

#### Template inline

The template literal used to define `card` could be moved out to a [template tag with slots](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots)  or a `<script type="text/template”>` that can be referenced by `id` attribute in the code. For more of an explanation of this, refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6932790/1575353), as well as an example application of it in [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/190088/120114). The requirements for this may be a bit complex for a beginner but the motivation is to keep the markup (i.e. HTML) separate from the business logic (i.e. JavaScript).

A script tag like this could be added to the body within the HTML:

```
<script type=“text/template” id=“card-template”>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="${logo}" alt="Card image cap" height="180" width="200">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">${name}</h5>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item">Watchers: ${forks}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Stars: ${stars}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Commits: ${issues}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Then that could be referenced via the JavaScript:

```
const cardTemplate = document.getElementById('card-template').innerHTML;
```

You would then need interpolate the string, and unfortunately that isn't in a template literal anymore. However, an approach like outlined in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41015840/1575353) should suffice.

The following function added in the JavaScript like this:

```
String.prototype.interpolate = function(params) {
  const names = Object.keys(params);
  const vals = Object.values(params);
  return new Function(...names, `return \`${this}\`;`)(...vals);
}
```

Would allow for a line like this:

```
row.innerHTML += cardTemplate.interpolate(data);
```

#### Simplifying single line returns in arrow statements

Arrow functions that simply have one line in the block, like:

> ```
> resp => {
>   return resp.json();
> }
> ```

Can be simplified to a single line without the block and `return`:

```
resp => resp.json()
```

#### Unused variable

The following variable doesn't appear to be utilized:

> ```
> let now = new Date();
> ```

It can be removed unless you plan to utilize it in the future. If the value never changes, it would be wise to declare it with [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).

### Putting it all together

See simplified code below.

```js
String.prototype.interpolate = function(params) {
  const names = Object.keys(params);
  const vals = Object.values(params);
  return new Function(...names, `return \`${this}\`;`)(...vals);
}
const frameworks = [{
    name: "angular",
    logo: "img/angular.png",
    url: "https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular.js"
  },
  {
    name: "ember",
    logo: "img/ember.png",
    url: "https://api.github.com/repos/emberjs/ember.js"
  },
  {
    name: "react",
    logo: "img/react.png",
    url: "https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react"
  },
  {
    name: "vue",
    logo: "img/vue.png",
    url: "https://api.github.com/repos/vuejs/vue"
  }
];

const frameworkData = framework => {
  return fetch(framework.url)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => {
      return {
          logo: framework.logo,
          name: data.name,
          forks: data.forks_count,
          stars: data.stargazers_count,
          issues: data.open_issues_count
      };
    });
};

const setup = () => {
  const row = document.getElementById("row");
  const cardTemplate = document.getElementById('card-template').innerHTML;
  const promises = frameworks.map(framework => frameworkData(framework));
  Promise.all(promises).then(data => {
    row.innerHTML = data.map(obj => cardTemplate.interpolate(obj));
  });
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setup);
```

```html
<div id="row"></div>
<script type="text/template" id="card-template">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src="${logo}" alt="Card image cap" height="180" width="200">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">${name}</h5>
      </div>
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item">Watchers: ${forks}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Stars: ${stars}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Commits: ${issues}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `"data"` property of the object returned from `.then()` chained to `fetch()` is not necessary as it is not used. Simply returning the object will suffice.

Use `.map()` instead of `.forEach()` to process array of `fetch()` calls made when `frameworks` is iterated.

`Promise.all()` returns an array of resolved `Promise` objects in the same order as the elements within the iterable passed to the function, whether the element is a `Promise` or not. Note also, that a single error or rejected `Promise` stops `Promise.all()` from further iteration.

Chain `.catch()` to both `Promise.all()` and `setup()` to include error handling for the asynchronous function calls, and `return` a value from `.then()` chained to `Promise.all()`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="row"></div>
  <script>
    const frameworks = [{
      name: "angular",
      logo: "img/angular.png",
      url: "https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular.js"
    }, {
      name: "ember",
      logo: "img/ember.png",
      url: "https://api.github.com/repos/emberjs/ember.js"
    }, {
      name: "react",
      logo: "img/react.png",
      url: "https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react"
    }, {
      name: "vue",
      logo: "img/vue.png",
      url: "https://api.github.com/repos/vuejs/vue"
    }];

    const handleError = err => {throw err};

    const frameworkData = url =>
      fetch(url)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => 
        ({
          name: data.name,
          forks: data.forks_count,
          stars: data.stargazers_count,
          issues: data.open_issues_count
        })
      ).catch(handleError);

    const setup = (
      row = document.getElementById("row")
    , now = new Date()
    ) => 
      Promise.all(
        frameworks.map(({url,logo,name:n}) => 
          frameworkData(url)
          .then(({forks,stars,issues}) => 
            row.innerHTML += `
              <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                  <img src="${logo}" alt="Card image cap" height="180" width="200">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">${n}</h5>
                  </div>
                  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <li class="list-group-item">Watchers: ${forks}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Stars: ${stars}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Commits: ${issues}</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>`))
            ).catch(handleError);

    setup()
    .then(() => console.log("done fetching frameworks data"))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Async would be better.

How time flies, the promise API was the bees knees, but now it looks old and messy. Async functions are the way to go.

This review is just a quicky as I found points and there is a very basic example that address the following points.

---

- Transformer?

I don't understand why you transform the data after you get it (example you change `forks_count` to `forks`, and so on). This looks like a  unnecessary step as you only use the data to fill a card and then you dump it.

- `Promise.all` for related data.

Only use `Promise.all` when the various data items you are waiting on are dependent on each other.

- Promise is dead, Long live Async.

`async functions` are much better than `Promise`. Async functions let you use promises without the need to create promises, define the callback functions that service the them, and write `then` over and over again. async functions are a promise without all the pleading...

- Markup where it belongs.

Use a HTML `<template>` element to define the card. Javascript strings are not the place for HTML, and adding content to the page via markup and `element.innerHTML` is about the slowest way to add content to a page.

HTML is designed to hold data. Use an element's `data` property to associate data to content. Eg the `<li>` elements have the property `data-field` which holds the name of data field it will display `<li data-field="forks_count">Watchers:</li>`

- Construct the page, then fill it.

Laying out the page as you get data makes the page feel sluggish, prevents the client navigating any existing content as reflows and new content move everything about.

Use placeholders for the cards and always give feedback (spinners show errors).

- Don't repeat yourself (DRY)

The array `frameworks` repeats the same API url `"https://api.github.com/repos/"` for each item (very easy to miss a typo in repeated code). Each item also repeats the framework name 3 times.

### Example

This is a very basic example using async. The `HTML` and the array `frameworks` is now stored as markup.

The function `createCard` handles the request and parses the JSON. When the data is ready, using a template it fills relevant fields and returns the new card.

The card is added to the DOM when the  async function resolves, or there is an error.

The entry point is the outer function `addCards` that will add cards to the array of `elements`. (there is no vetting)

```
function addCards(elements) {
  async function createCard({name, ext = ""}) {
    const card = document.importNode(frameworkCard.content, true);        
    const fields = card.querySelectorAll("li");
    const fillEl = (qry, prop, el=card.querySelector(qry))=>el && Object.assign(el, prop);

    const data = await (await fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/" + name + ext)).json();
    fillEl("img", {src : `img/${name}.png`});
    fillEl(".card-title", {textContent : name});
    for (const el of fields) { el.textContent += data[el.dataset.field] }
    return card;
  }        
  for (const el of elements) {
    createCard(el.dataset)
      .then(card => (el.textContent = "", el.appendChild(card)))
      .catch(() => el.textContent = "Error");
  }
}
addCards(document.querySelectorAll(".card-container"));
```

### Where the cards will go.

The array of elements that are the placeholders for the cards. They also contain the data that is required to make the API calls for that card.

```
<div class="card-container" data-name="angular" data-ext=".js">Loading</div>    
<div class="card-container" data-name="ember" data-ext=".js">Loading</div>
<div class="card-container" data-name="react">Loading</div>
<div class="card-container" data-name="vue">Loading</div>
```

### The template

that is used to create a card. It is automatically not part of the page layout thus does not incur overhead until you import it and add it to the DOM.

```
<template id="frameworkCard">
    <img height="180" width="200">
    <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li data-field="forks_count">Watchers:</li>
        <li data-field="stargazers_count">Stars:</li>
        <li data-field="open_issues_count">Commits:</li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

Comment: _"Promise is dead"_? When did `Promise` become "dead"? _"`async` functions are much better than `Promise`"_ An `async` function still returns a `Promise`. How are you defining "better"?

Comment: @guest271314 Stillborn (well on life support) due to the need to use a callback to get data or pass data from one promise to the next. Life support turned off when Async was born "An `async function` still returns a `Promise`" I did point that out.

Comment: Since you insist on stating that `Promise` is "dead", how would you replace `new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 1))` with an `async` function without using `Promise` constructor?

Comment: @guest271314 OK without using `Promise` constructor. How about `(async () => Promise.resolve({then(t) { setTimeout(t, 1000) }}))().then(()=>log("One second"))`

Comment: While the code does not use `Promise` constructor, the code still uses `Promise.resolve()`. The `async` function used in the code is not necessary to achieve the same result using only `Promise.resolve()` as you demonstrate or `Promise` constructor and `.then()`. Does that not prove that `Promise` is not "dead"?

Comment: @guest271314  "dead" is a metaphor that I used  to dissuade people from using promises directly and consider `async function`s. The absurdity 
 of  `waitForIt().then(result => data = result );` should be self evident when `data = await waitForIt();` is identical. The OP did not use an `async function` opting incorrectly for `Promise.all`. With two answers not correcting the OP I paraphrased the trope "promise chaining is dead, long live async/await" (look it up) to make the point

Comment: `(async()=>)() instanceof Promise // true`. Not sure what you mean by OP _"opting incorrectly for `Promise.all`"_ OP or _"With two answers not correcting the OP"_? What is "incorrect about OP's usage of `Promise.all()`? Setting aside your campaigning for `async/await`, how does the code at this users' answer not correctly use `Promise.all()`? _"(look it up)"_ Are you referring to a blog post where the author opines about `Promise` and `async/await`?

Comment: @guest271314 `Promise.all` is for dependent datasets. For independent datasets it is bad design. Your answer points out, 1 fails and all fail. Over poor quality / slow networks the more requests the less likely the client will see any result. On average networks `Promise.all` makes the page feel sluggish. Async func is the correct way,. My example is not ideal, but not guessing OPs needs (Request only visible, or visable first, rate limiting, are needed) . Re "look it up", Sorry was frequency of the trope I wanted to convey , not any particular article. Space in comments too short

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "dependent" and "independent" datasets. The entire concept of "bad design" is completely subjective. The code can be (minimally) adjusted to return both resolved and rejected `Promise` or other values whether a single `Promise` or other value is rejected or throws an error or not by utilizing `.catch()` and `return` within `.map()` . How do you objectively qualify "Makes the page feel sluggish"?  Still not following what you mean by "look it up".

Comment: Dependent data can not be processed without the dependencies, while independent data can. . Sluggish means network feels slow, the client.must wait rather than be continuously engaged.   "Good design" is by its very nature not subjective